# Wrong number of favorites in network profile for some users

Tags: bug, profile-page, bookmarks, stackexchange.com, network-profile

For some users, the number of favorites in one of his/her StackExchange accounts does not match that in his/her network profile.

For example,

- User Pang (me):

  - [In stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1402846/pang?tab=favorites) = 4
  - [For stackoverflow.com, in network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/1497191/pang?tab=favorites) = 5

- User Jon Skeet:

  - [In stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=favorites) = 3
  - [For stackoverflow.com, in network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/11683/jon-skeet?tab=favorites) = 4

- User Servy:

  - [In meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/186381/servy?tab=favorites) = 4
  - [For meta.stackoverflow.com, in network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/1185389/servy?tab=favorites) = 5

---

In my case, I am currently having 4 favorites, so the network profile is wrong. There's [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871050) that I am not favoriting but appearing favorited on the network profile. Maybe I favorited it before and unfavorited it later, I don't remember, but even so, that would be months ago.

Not sure about the other users.

Comment: Asking the obvious: Which one's wrong for you? (I.E. do you see the lit star on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871050/inconsistent-scope-of-use-strict-on-different-web-browsers-concerning-argument), indicating it's missing from the SO version, or do you see the empty star, indicating it's added to the SE one by mistake?

Comment: @BillyMailman No, no lit star. I am not favoriting that question. Maybe I did before, I don't remember, sorry.

Comment: If you had it as a favourite before, then it's caching. It's always caching. Specifically, it's that basically all network-wide profile stuff is cached based off your various separate accounts, and it tends to be a day or so out of date in place.

Comment: @BillyMailman Added details to question. Thanks.

Comment: SE network sites and the SE site are 2 different pages with different caching

Comment: @m0sa A cache that doesn't get invalidated for months despite a change is plain broken.