# Zero favorites question in Network profile - favorites tab

Tags: bug, network-profile, favorites-tab

In my [Network profile - favorites tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/2855348/arulkumar?tab=favorites), there are few questions with zero favorites.

[image: Network profile - zero favorites]

This is something strange to me. As my knowledge I didn't favorite those questions, so we can't blame caching.

I can see this zero favorites questions in other user's network profile too.

Comment: I got [lots of these](https://stackexchange.com/users/1497191/pang?tab=favorites). Anyway, related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216327