# Favorites list still shows questions I un-marked as favorite

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, bookmarks

I had a long list of favorite questions. I un-marked many of them. A few of the questions still show up in the "favorites" list. Why? Am I doing something wrong? Is it a bug? or a feature...?

I haven't done anything fancy, I simply opened the questions pages and toggled (off) the favorite mark.

**Edit**: Examples may be

[Why does cold metal seem colder than cold air?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/119688/why-does-cold-metal-seem-colder-than-cold-air) (physics.stackexchange.com)

[Why isn't the 3 body problem solvable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146457/why-isnt-the-3-body-problem-solvable) (math.stackexchange.com)

**Edit2**: the questions have been un-marked long time ago (say months)

**Edit3**: (after @rene's comment)

They are listed at the global(?) favorites page: https://stackexchange.com/users/1822217/rolazaro-azeveires?tab=favorites

They indeed are *not* listed at each sites favorites' ages (as linked by rene) I never use those, so I haven't noticed it.

Comment: It doesn't show up for me: https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/12068/rolazaro-azeveires?tab=favorites nor here: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/39752/rolazaro-azeveires?tab=favorites&sort=added&page=1 do you mind adding a screenshot for what you see?

Comment: @rene Oh! Interesting. I don't see them at each sites' favorites page either, but they are listed at the global page (see edit3 above).

Comment: Definitely something wrong in that view indeed. This one I noticed in my list: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw5lC.png that is this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303093/bug-u200b-and-u200c-characters-added-to-code-snippet-in-comment) which not favorited anymore by anyone.

Comment: @rene OK, now what? Someone will catch this here? Do I report somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, the bug tag is watched by SE staff. Doesn't guarantee it gets handled within 6 to 8 weeks but beyond reporting here there is nothing much else you can do. You can consider to stalk an SE Developer (in chat, a comment, twitter)  but based on tone of voice and how persistent you are the bug gets solved or you get suspended.

Comment: Very much related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216327/wrong-number-of-favorites-in-network-profile-for-some-users /cc @rene

Comment: @rene. Thanks. If there is a chance it gets seen here, that is enough for me. If they choose to have a notorious feature with a bug that cripples it for 4 years (according to ShadowWizard's comment) it is they that look bad.

Comment: And indeed they look bad.